# Not use distinct, use group by is not working

Tags: sql

```
SELECT  
    COALESCE(TranscriptCourses.SSID, CourseMemberhsip.SSID) SSID,
    COALESCE(CourseMemberhsip.DATE_OF_BIRTH ,TranscriptCourses.DATE_OF_BIRTH) DATE_OF_BIRTH,    
    COALESCE(CourseMemberhsip.DISTRICT_NUMBER , CourseMemberhsip.DISTRICT_NUMBER ) DISTRICT_NUMBER,
    TranscriptCourses.SCHOOL_NUMBER ,
    COALESCE(CourseMemberhsip.STATE_COURSE_CODE, TranscriptCourses.CORE_CODE) STATE_COURSE_CODE ,
    ISNULL(CourseMemberhsip.SECTION_EXIT_DATE, '9999-01-01') SECTION_EXIT_DATE ,
    (CourseMemberhsip.AvgGradeEarned, TranscriptCourses.AvgGradeEarned) AS AvgGradeEarned ,
    TranscriptCourses.SCHOOL_YEAR
FROM
    #transcripts TranscriptCourses
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    #GradeMembership CourseMemberhsip ON TranscriptCourses.SSID = CourseMemberhsip.SSID
                                      AND TranscriptCourses.CORE_CODE = CourseMemberhsip.STATE_COURSE_CODE
                                      AND TranscriptCourses.SCHOOL_YEAR = CourseMemberhsip.SCHOOL_YEAR
GROUP BY 
    SSID,
    STATE_COURSE_CODE,
    TranscriptCourses.SCHOOL_YEAR
```

Comment: you can only use group by colums in select part

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using "group by", all of your columns either should be declared in group by clause also, or should be applied an aggregate function like sum, avg, count, min, max, etc...

Also group by is not applied after the selection completes, I mean you have to include your columns exactly they are in select clause (in your query you only included the result alias as SSID in your group by clause, it should be GROUP BY COALESCE(TranscriptCourses.SSID, CourseMemberhsip.SSID) without the alias part.

And there are columns that exist in the select clause but neither included in group by clause nor applied an aggregate function over them (DATE_OF_BIRTH, SCHOOL_NUMBER)

you should fix these issues before expecting your query to run.

I suggest you to read about writing select queries with group operations...